# how to use c++ from visual studio 2010 professional - I only see templates for c# and F#

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I want to compile some open source C into a x64 dll for azure.

I have Visual Studio Professional, but only C# and F# are showing up in project templates, no C++.

How do I get C or C++ project templates to show up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have installed support for C++ you'll see the templates under **Other languages** in the new project window (That if you didn't set your environment for C++ development during the first run)

[image: VS2010 New Project window with VC++ installed]

Otherwise you have to run VS2010 setup again and install VC++ support

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-run the Visual Studio installer and modify the installed packages; select the Visual C++ packages for installation, and once the installer completes, they will be available.

Comment: That's right adam, thanks.  Marked Nacereddine as answer since he was first AND had example.